# How to authenticate a request to an Apache server using Firebase

Tags: apache, firebase, request, firebase-authentication

Currently I'm using Firebase to authenticate users for my Angular application and store their data, but I'm also using a separate Apache server as the backend to run some functions (also for my Angular app). I would like to know if there is a way to authenticate a request to my server checking whether the user that made that request is logged in or not in my front-end application.

To sum up:
Is there a way to check if the user sending the request was already logged in my app?

Comment: How does your data is passed from Firebase to your server? Via cloud functions, the Firebase API, an xhr call, etc? And what runtime do you run on your back-end?

Comment: Just edited the question providing more information. Firebase is not directly communicating with my Apache server, what I want is to see if there is a way to find if a request was send to my Apache server via an already logged in user in my Angular app (maybe use some token id, idk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this. I used the [Firebase ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). Firstly, the user must login in my Angular application via Firebase. Once this is done, I can get the tokenId from the user as explained

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

After this, in your server, you can verify the recived token. You can use either the Firebase SDK as shown in the docs, or a third party JWT (JSON Web Token) library.